# Exception caught by flutter test framework

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have the following widget tests, when I run nothing test the test passes normally, but when I run all the main I have an error.

The test I have corresponds to the following:

```
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('initial status of login page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    Widget widget = LoginPage();

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      home: widget,
      locale: Locale('en'),
      supportedLocales: lang.getSupportedLocales(),
      localizationsDelegates: lang.localizationsDelegates,
      localeResolutionCallback: lang.getLocaleResolutionCallback,
    ));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.text(lang.translate('login.welcome')), findsOneWidget);
  });

  testWidgets('enter an invalid email', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    Widget widget = LoginPage();

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      home: widget,
      locale: Locale('en'),
      supportedLocales: lang.getSupportedLocales(),
      localizationsDelegates: lang.localizationsDelegates,
      localeResolutionCallback: lang.getLocaleResolutionCallback,
    ));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final Finder emailInputFinder = find.byKey(Key('emailInput'));
    final Finder passwordInputFinder = find.byKey(Key('passwordInput'));
    final Finder signInButtonFinder = find.byKey(Key('signInButton'));

    await tester.tap(emailInputFinder);
    await tester.enterText(emailInputFinder, 'email');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(passwordInputFinder, 'password');
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(signInButtonFinder, findsNothing);
  });
}
```

The error that while in the console is:

```
        ✓  initial status of login page
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown running a test:
Bad state: No element

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Iterable.single (dart:core/iterable.dart:498:25)
#1      WidgetController._getElementPoint (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:814:47)
#2      WidgetController.getCenter (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:786:12)
#3      WidgetController.tap (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:257:18)
#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/ezequiel/Documents/Larvia/lrv-mobile-app/test/widget_test/login2_test.dart:45:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

The test description was:
  enter an invalid email
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: enter an invalid email
```

Please I need help, if you have any ideas I thank you for your time.

Comment: Having the same issue, I print the finder result before the tap function and yields a single widget, fid you found what was causing this issue